# Create these tables: Could not create constraint or index: Datatype mismatch

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure

Can anyone me figure out why I'm getting this error and spot my mistake here?

I read the error message but I can't spot the different data types? What am I missing?

```
CREATE TABLE STAFF (
    StaffLastname NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,     
    StaffFirstName  NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL, 
    StaffID NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (StaffID)   
);

CREATE TABLE WAREHOUSE(
    WarehouseLocation NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (WarehouseLocation) 
);

CREATE TABLE CUSTOMER (
    CustomerID NVARCHAR(50),        
    CustomerName  NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    CustomerAddress NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    CustomerCity  NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (CustomerID)    
);

CREATE TABLE COURSE (
    CourseID    NVARCHAR(25),
    CourseName  NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (CourseID)  
);

CREATE TABLE COURSE_OFFERING (
    WarehouseLocation NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    CourseID NVARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
    CourseDate DATE CHECK (LEN(CourseDate) = 8),
    PRIMARY KEY (WarehouseLocation,CourseID,CourseDate), 
    FOREIGN KEY (CourseID) REFERENCES COURSE,
    FOREIGN KEY (WarehouseLocation) REFERENCES WAREHOUSE
);

CREATE TABLE  BOOKING (
    CustomerID NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,   
    WarehouseLocation NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,   
    CourseID NVARCHAR(25) NOT NULL, 
    CourseDate DATE CHECK (LEN(CourseDate) = 8),
    BookingDate DATE CHECK (LEN(BookingDate) = 8),
    PaymentAmount MONEY CHECK (PaymentAmount > 0) NOT NULL, 
    Review NVARCHAR(100) NULL,    
    PRIMARY KEY (CustomerID, WarehouseLocation, CourseID, CourseDate),  
    FOREIGN KEY (WarehouseLocation, CourseID, CourseDate) REFERENCES COURSE_OFFERING,
    FOREIGN KEY (CustomerID) REFERENCES CUSTOMER
);

CREATE TABLE STAFF_ALLOCATION (
    StaffID NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    CourseDate DATE CHECK (LEN(CourseDate) = 8),
    WarehouseLocation NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    CourseID NVARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (StaffID, CourseDate, CourseID, WarehouseLocation),
    FOREIGN KEY (StaffID) REFERENCES STAFF,
    FOREIGN KEY (CourseDate, WarehouseLocation, CourseID) REFERENCES COURSE_OFFERING
);

ERROR MSG - - -- - - - - - - - - - -
```

> (1 row affected)
> Msg 1778, Level 16, State 0, Line 65 Column 'COURSE_OFFERING.WarehouseLocation' is not the same data type as
> referencing column 'STAFF_ALLOCATION.CourseDate' in foreign key
> 'FK__STAFF_ALLOCATION__5D60DB10'.
>
> Msg 1750, Level 16, State 1, Line 65 Could not create constraint or
> index. See previous errors.

[image: This is the ERD i have]

Comment: I think since you don't specify the referenced column name(s) of the parent table by default it takes the order of the column definition in COURSE_OFFERING.

Comment: There are two solutions, 1. Mention the foreign reference column names `REFERENCES COURSE_OFFERING (CourseDate, WarehouseLocation, CourseID)` in STAFF_ALLOCATION table. 2. Change the column order in  STAFF_ALLOCATION equivalent to COURSE_OFFERING i.e., WAREHOUSELOCATION, COURSEID, COURSEDATE

Comment: Option 2 - Any difference from my answer ?

Comment: @antonio_mg you do not have to delete your answer, just wanted to check if there is something more to that answer...Cheers!

Comment: Just out of curiosity: Why do you have the check constraint on the `date` columns?

Comment: @Pred,  it was something that i thought would help - but realised later was pointless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your last table you have a foreign key that has 3 columns with this order of data type's:
DATE, NVARCHAR, NVARCHAR

and they reference to a table that has 3 columns with this order of data type's:

NVARCHAR, NVARCHAR, DATE

If you change your last table to this:

```
CREATE TABLE STAFF_ALLOCATION (
StaffID NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
CourseDate DATE CHECK (LEN(CourseDate) = 8),
WarehouseLocation NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
CourseID NVARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (StaffID, CourseDate, CourseID, WarehouseLocation),
FOREIGN KEY (StaffID) REFERENCES STAFF,
FOREIGN KEY (WarehouseLocation, CourseID, CourseDate) REFERENCES COURSE_OFFERING
```

All will be fine as it is in this [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=6ce486bc87d60948703e2c5aff89c9ae)

Answer (score 0):

Adjust the order of the columns in the PRIMARY KEY in the COURSE OFFERING table with the columns in the FOREIGN KEY in the STAFF_ALLOCATION table.
because before,
WarehouseLocation, CourseID, CourseDate = NVARCHAR, NVARCHAR, DATE at COURSE OFFERING
CourseDate, WarehouseLocation, CourseID = DATE, NVARCHAR, NVARCHAR

```
CREATE TABLE COURSE_OFFERING (
    WarehouseLocation NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    CourseID NVARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
    CourseDate DATE CHECK (LEN(CourseDate) = 8),
    PRIMARY KEY (WarehouseLocation,CourseID,CourseDate)
);

CREATE TABLE STAFF_ALLOCATION (
    StaffID NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    CourseDate DATE CHECK (LEN(CourseDate) = 8),
    WarehouseLocation NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    CourseID NVARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (StaffID, CourseDate, CourseID, WarehouseLocation),
    FOREIGN KEY (WarehouseLocation,CourseID,CourseDate) REFERENCES COURSE_OFFERING
);
```